# Play @Before(unless={"login", "authenticate", "logout"})?

Tags: playframework

If i declare @Before(unless={"login", "authenticate", "logout"}) before the method in play framework.

what is does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this description is all you need. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/controllers#interceptions